# Nginx: how to add /something to a uri and still keep it working

Tags: nginx, configuration, server

I have a nginx instance running. My config is something like the following.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    location / {
        ...
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        ...
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 example.com;

    }
}
```

I have some software running in 8080 and I want that the user enters `example.com/somepath` and be able to be redirected to the root 127.0.0.1:8080 through my domain. The software should receive all urls without `/somepath` but the browser should still show `/somepath` in the name.

I am quite new so sorry for the basic question I could not find any relevant info on how to do this exactly: I tried rewrite rules and setting `location /mysoftware {` tests with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The client browser uses `/somepath/...` to access `/...`in the application. This means that `nginx` must rewrite the URI before passing it upstream.

The `proxy_pass` directive has a basic rewrite capability. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details. For example:

```
location /somepath/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you might use a `rewrite ... break` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. For example:

```
location /somepath {
    rewrite ^/somepath/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    ...
}
```

The difficult part is preventing your application from breaking out of */somepath*. The `proxy_redirect` directive can handle the 3xx responses from your application. But the location of resource files (`.css` and `.js`) and the target for hyperlinks, can cause problems for applications that are not aware that they need to stay inside a subdirectory.